# PowerShell with System Window Form Objects How to display command pane or confim boxes

Tags: winforms, shell, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a PowerShell Script that I like to run with a Visual Interface (GUI - with Windows Form elements) Everything is working so far but I have one big problem:

Is it possible to display the command pane from PowerShell on the created Windows Form?
**For Example**: In one part of my PowerShell Script I am running the following command:

```
Upgrade-SPContentDatabase DBName
```

This command requires to confirm some messages with "Yes/No" that will be normally displayed in the command pane from PowerShell... Can this be done over the Windows Form so that I can hide the PowerShell-Script Window in the background?

Or is there any other way to display it in a new window that comes up?

Screenshot:
[image]

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A `messagebox` (GUI) is different from a prompt. As long as you run a script in powershell console(not ISE), prompts will show up in the console. (There may be a setting to make them GUI like in ISE).  A workaround would be to try and disable the confirm-prompts in the script, and create a `messagebox` yourself.

Try the following in your button's click-handler:

```
$handler_button1_Click= 
{
    $n = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Are you sure?", "Confirm", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo)
    if ($n -eq "Yes") {
        #Ignore confirm dialogs with -Confirm:$false
        Upgrade-SPContentDatabase DBName -Confirm:$false
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. This was also my first idea... But some information in these dialogs are important for me.